# SaaS database design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm designing a database for a SaaS. As a rough explanation I can say that we will have:

- Account (our clients)
- Client (our clients clients)
- Appointment (appointments made by some client or by some person that hasn't a client account yet)

[image]
Analysing this use case I came up with a redundancy database dependency. I want your help to understand if this is the best way to do it and if you have some suggestions on this design.

**Questions:**

1. Do you think this type of dependency is the best way to solve this use case? If not, how do you do it?
2. In legal wise do you think I should have a different database for tenant? I want to make an MVP (startup wise) to test and put the business running, so I'm having serious doubts if I should address this from the start, but I want to have a clear roadmap.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**, you don't have any circular dependency in your database design (data model). 
Definition: (from wikipedia) a circular dependency is a relation between two or more modules which either directly or indirectly depend on each other to function properly.

**Second**: your data model has Redundancy. There is no need to relationship between Account and Appointment. 
if each CLIENT related to only one ACCOUNT, so each APPOINTMENT of each CLIENT is related to one ACCOUNT too. The relationship between APPOINTMENT and ACCOUNT can be reached from relationship of CLIENT and ACCOUNT.

**Finally**: for your second question, having other databases for tenants, the answer is related to many parameters like your project size, number of clients and etc.

Comment: I've made a type, you're absolutely right is redundancy.
Trying to explain further, I can have an appointment made without having a client entry. For example: You receive a call from mr John saying he wants an appointment at 15h, in this case you will not make the client sheet on the phone and you have to make an appointment nonetheless.

I hope I was clear, if you have any doubt of the use case, please ask. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you want to Insert into Appointment without specific Client ID? You should save new phone call Client's basic information like phone, name, and etc. 
So, the best solution is : Insert new Client entry and new Appointment entry in a transaction, so you can delete Account-Appointment relationship.
In GUI, you do not need to open new form to Client entry and in Client table, you can use a type field to distinguish ordinary Client with phone call Clients.

Comment: Imagine a case that a father does an appointment to a child, the number he will be giving his the same as his number, so I can't use the phone number as index :(